# How to parse this datetime in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, utc, iso8601

I'm trying to parse this DateTime, but unable to detect the formatting and got no luck with parsing. It looks like the following:

```
20190507T000000.000
```

I tried every format I was able to imagine, but honestly, I'm far away from date format understanding. I tried to set this format to dateFormatter as I think this most close to it:

```
"yyyyMMddTHHmmss.sss"
```

Also, I tried to use `ISO8601DateFormatter()` which gave me nothing. I guess this DateTime is some UTC date.

Comment: Refer this to understand the different date formats : https://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html

Comment: You are close. You need `"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS"`. Note the `T` needs to be escaped since it is a literal, not a format specifier, and the fractional seconds use `S`, not `s`.

Comment: @rmaddy please convert you comment into the full answer so I mark it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Created one extension of String.

```
extension String {

extension String {

public func dateIn(formate: String) -> Date? { // gives in same formate
    if formate.isEmpty { return Date() }
    
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    formatter.dateFormat = formate
    if let dt = formatter.date(from: self) {
        return dt
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

How to use :

```
let stringValue : String = "20190507T000000.000"
print(stringValue.dateIn(formate: "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSS"))
```

Comment: Why did you extend `String`? And why did you return `Date()` on failure?

Comment: Because 20190507T000000.000 is a string type,

Comment: I tested your code, it returns nil. You need to escape the T: `"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.sss"`.

Comment: in my playground , it is working fine. getting 2019-11-07 15:01:21 +0000

Comment: The `.sss` needs to be `.SSS` and the `T` needs to be escaped as `'T'`.

Comment: What is `GTM`? Did you mean `GMT`? That's the same as UTC. If you want a parameter that means "use GMT or use local time" then your logic is all wrong.

Comment: Your `isGMT` logic is still wrong. If false you want to use the user's local time. That's the same as not setting the timezone at all.

Comment: That's not needed. The date formatter defaults to the user's current timezone (and locale).

Comment: One last suggestion. None of your answer is necessary. The OP only needed to know what was wrong with their nearly correct date format. Your answer doesn't actually make any attempt to explain what the OP had wrong. Your answer never actually fixed the problem until you fixed your date format at my suggestion. To make your answer truly correct, explain what the OP had wrong. All the code you added is just extra fluff not really needed to answer the question.